# Stop my first person character controller going through the wall in Unity using C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As seen in the video here: https://i.gyazo.com/ad45ef9e231fd2f9ec6d4cf76889aece.mp4

My code:

**MouseLook.cs:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
public enum RotationAxes { MouseXAndY = 0, MouseX = 1, MouseY = 2 }
public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;
public float sensitivityX = 3F;
public float sensitivityY = 3F;
public Camera playerCamera;

public float minimumX = -360F;
public float maximumX = 360F;

public float minimumY = -60F;
public float maximumY = 60F;



private float rotationX = 0F;
private float rotationY = 0F;

private Quaternion originalRotation;

void Update()
{
    if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY)
    {
        rotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;
        rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;

        rotationX = ClampAngle(rotationX, minimumX, maximumX);
        rotationY = ClampAngle(rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

        Quaternion xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationX, Vector3.up);
        Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationY, -Vector3.right);

        transform.localRotation = originalRotation * xQuaternion * yQuaternion;
    }

    if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX)
    {
        rotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;
        rotationX = ClampAngle(rotationX, minimumX, maximumX);

        Quaternion xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationX, Vector3.up);
        transform.localRotation = originalRotation * xQuaternion;
    }

    if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseY || playerCamera != null)
    {
        rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
        rotationY = ClampAngle(rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

        Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-rotationY, Vector3.right);

        if (playerCamera != null)
        {
            playerCamera.transform.localRotation = originalRotation * yQuaternion;
        }
        else
        {
            transform.localRotation = originalRotation * yQuaternion;
        }
    }
}

void Start()
{
    /*
    if (gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
    }
    */
    originalRotation = transform.localRotation;
}

public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
{
    if (angle < -360F)
    {
        angle += 360F;
    }

    if (angle > 360F)
    {
        angle -= 360F;
    }

    return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
}
```

}

**FirstPersonController.cs:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;
using Cursor = UnityEngine.Cursor;




public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float speed = 5;
    private float jumpPower = 4;
    Rigidbody rb;
    CapsuleCollider col;
    public GameObject crossHair;
    bool isActive;
    float HorizontalInput;
    float VerticalInput;


    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        col = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
        crossHair = GameObject.FindWithTag("CrossHair");
    }


    void Update()
    {
        HorizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        VerticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("escape"))
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Sprint"))
        {
            speed = 15;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Sprint"))
        {
            speed = 5;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.H))
        {
            isActive = !isActive;
        }

        if (isActive)
        {
            crossHair.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            crossHair.SetActive(false);
        }

    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 xMovement = transform.right * speed * HorizontalInput * Time.deltaTime;
        Vector3 zMovement = transform.forward * speed * VerticalInput * Time.deltaTime;
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(HorizontalInput, 0, VerticalInput) * speed;



        if (isGrounded() && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))

        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpPower, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }


    private bool isGrounded()
    {
        return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, col.bounds.extents.y + 0.1f);
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing in this code, if so how do I fix it?

Entire project can be downloaded here: https://github.com/Some-T/FirstPersonController-CSharp

**Project has relevant colliders and rigidbodies set up!**

Someone has advised me to use shapecast, but I believe that may incorrect? I can't see how that would work as my player does not have character controller component added to it?

Overall how do I stop my first person character controller going through the wall like in the initial video specified above?

Upon further research I have discovered the following:

The answer is to use:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html as a quick fix.

But definitively for flawlessness use:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html

As to how in C# I am not so sure, but here is a screen shot I did in bolt asset.

[image]

Currently I have movmement working with velocity but it does not work properly, not sure as to why? So overall my question now is how do I get movement working using velocity? I added a line in FirstPersonController.cs that moves the character using velocity of `rb.velocity = new Vector3(HorizontalInput, 0, VerticalInput) * speed;` **so my only question and issue now is my player does not move in the direction the camera on my player is facing so I am not sure how to fix this specific thing overall?**

Comment: Is the rigid body on your player set to continuous or discrete collision detection? It should be continuous. Also if you don't want the player to see through the wall, change your camera's clipping plane.

Comment: Thank for your response. I have it set to continious. I changed the clipping plain, and visually it kinda gets rid of the problem, practically however I can still run through a wall or solid object.

Comment: Can you check again  that your colliders are covering the whole wall? Because it seems like there is only a specific part of the wall you can pass through.

Comment: Yes, they are mesh collider, thing is I have this exact same project with the only difference being is I used Bolt visual scripting and this has raycast (but this was only for crouching and ceiling check as in a tunnel ceiling) implemented, this works fine and the level is the same.I tried an experiment of making a pure solid object with Unity rather than using probuilder and I get the exact same issue with being able to walk through the wall. Sometimes running into a solid object will make the player jump really high into the air. They key here is figuring out the one thing I need to change?

Comment: Also is it definitely the whole entire wall this issue happens on the Unity object wall and probuilder mesh wall despite checking the colliders on them both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your project code is different from one that you provided here.
2. Try to enable rigidbody`s rotation constraint - freeze X and Z rotation, leave only Y. When you rotate your capsule collider (as it works in your project), it can "climb" on a wall.
3. Do the isGrounded check when you move, and lock movement, if not grounded.
4. Try to increase [Collider.contactOffset](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-contactOffset.html)
5. If above does not helps, try to use Rigidbody.velocity instead of Rigidbody.MovePosition.
6. You can also reduce Rigidbody.drag
7. In general, pretty good technique is to use NavMesh for movement - in this way, you able to explicitly lock player from movement outside of navmesh surface. But, of course, it doesn`t fit to many gameplays.

Hope, it helps.

upd
You move your player like this:

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 xMovement = transform.right * speed * HorizontalInput * Time.deltaTime;
        Vector3 zMovement = transform.forward * speed * VerticalInput * Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

Note, that you not even apply it to rigidbody;
But you get your input this way:

```
float HorizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");         
float VerticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
```

in Update, so input just stays inside Update, and does not applied at all. You declared your variables twice, once on class top, another in Update().

Comment: Also, to prevent looking through the wall, reduce camera`s near clipping plane.

Comment: I tried all this already, currently I am trying to implement velocity as a fix. Additionally the code via github link is best as its constantly being updated.

Comment: it's not even moved :) You move your player like this`: Vector3 xMovement = transform.right * speed * HorizontalInput * Time.deltaTime;
        Vector3 zMovement = transform.forward * speed * VerticalInput * Time.deltaTime;` in FixedUpdate, but you get your input this way: `float HorizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float VerticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");` in Update, so input just stays inside Update, and does not applied at all :)

Comment: And I look in the editor, and see your rigidbody rotated, even if constraints are set - it`s because you rotate it directly in your MouseLook script. I bet the climbing effect is caused by that.

Comment: Could you please put that into an answer, its extremely difficult to read in the comments.

Comment: My biggest issue is that I can not update the code on stack overflow relative to how much I am updating it on Github, but my all means I can try. Currently I am implementing velocity but its not working correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215843/discussion-between-somet-and-mykhailo-khadzhynov).